# Intel HD Graphics freeze on 16.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, 16.10

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10. My laptop freezes frequently after the installation.

I have an `Intel i5-6440 HQ CPU (HD Graphics 530)` and an `nVidia GTX 960M`. With the nVidia drivers installed, everything works perfectly (except my battery drains fast and the fan of my GPU spins up regularly). However, when I switch to the integrated graphics whether with **PRIME** or just use the default driver, my system become unstable and freezes frequently; during boot, during working and during shutdown.

Also when I start the settings app the system always freezes if the nVidia driver isn't active.
I tried installing **Bumblebee**, without luck: same issues.
Any help on how to get this work properly?

Thanks in advance!